# Using Google Map v3 zoom animation and hint outside map.google.com

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I am using google map v3,and I know the basic usage of the map following the tutorials.

However I found that the map I created are quite different with that in map.google.

1) the zoom animation.

In map.google.com,when I zoom in and out,the tiles will be zoomed accordingly,then the new tiles are to be loaded,it is smmoth,however,in the map created by myself,there is no smooth animation between the zoom.

2) the zoom hint.

In map.google.com,when I zoom in and out,I can see this(the red hint):

[image]

3) the inertia in map move.

In map.google.com,when I move the map(drag and drop) quickly,the map will have a inertia,it means that even I have droped the mouse,the map will still move for a certain distance before stop. And this is distance is quite large,however in the map I created,I can hardly find this inertia.

What is the problem?

Comment: There is no problem. What's implemented on maps.google.com is one thing, while the Google Maps API is another.

Comment: @Marcelo:Any suggestion if I want to make the same effecttion? Client like the animation in map.google.

Comment: Sure, my suggestion is do your research, give it a try and if you run into problems post a *specific* question, in accordance with the stackoverflow guidelines: http://stackoverflow.com/faq

Comment: @hguser it depends on your browser, Chrome for example renders all API created maps as they appear to you on maps.google.com currently. Firefox is terrible at rendering the maps and is always jerky. IE9 is a little better than firefox.

Answer (score 0):

When I had this problem, I found that I neglected to specify 'version 3' in my script tag.

`src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=`...`&sensor=false"`

needed to be changed to

`src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=`...`&sensor=false&v=3.exp"`

It may be that I was indeed using version 3, and this code is simply changing it to version 3 experimental, I am not sure.